# Python image cropping, "tile cannot extend outside image"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to crop the image to make it square. For that, i am trying to crop left and right side if width is greater and cropping top and bottom if height is greater. Below is the code i am trying but it says "tile cannot extend outside image". Can anyone explain me where i am doing wrong?

```
    if height != width:
        if height < width:
            left = (width - height) / 2
            print(left)
            right = (width - height) / 2
            print(right)
            top = 0
            bottom = 0
            img = img.crop(x(left, top, right, bottom))

        elif width < height:
            left = 0
            right = 0
            top = (height - width) / 2
            bottom = (height - width) / 2
            img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
        
        img.save(image_path)
```

Comment: The fact that you use the same formula for both `left` and `right` should tell you something has gone wrong... plus any decimals (you want integer dimensions).

Comment: @MarkSetchell Same formula? I didn't got it.

Comment: Your `left` is `(width-height)/2`. So is your `right`. Because you use the same formula. So `left` equals `right`, so your image is zero pixels wide.